# How do I unlock all 5 endings?

Tags: kingsway

According to [this guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1097961312), Kingsway has 5 endings.  Unfortunately, endings 3 (Destroyer) and 5 (Sacrifice) aren't filled out.  If you ask on the forums, everyone says "search the forums", which I've done.

So, how do you get all the endings, and what are the rewards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](https://steamcommunity.com/app/588950/discussions/0/1458455461495129660/?ctp=2) seems to have your answer.

In summary:

- **Martyr** - Play through the game normally.  Light all three beacons, visit the final castle, fight the king's guard, then destroy the Sky Eater's Heart.  Unlocks 'Worthless' class.
- **Ascended** - Use three feathers dropped by bosses in graveyard dungeons *(purple/cyan ones, not the beehive ones)*. Make it to the sky eater's heart (above), but talk to it instead of attacking.  Unlocks 'Ascended' class
- **Sacrifice** - Activate all 5 monoliths by donating a magical (blue) item to each.  Enter the underworld via the archway and snuff out the three torches. Then visit the red inverted crown, and choose "Power" --> "Sacrifice Self".  Unlocks ???
- **Dark Lord** - Same as Sacrifice, but attack the Demon Lord.  Choose 'Stay in Underworld' after defeating him.  Unlocks 'Demonblood' class.
- **Destroyer** - Wait until the dark-cloud covers the entire Overworld. You'll then encounter the Sky Eater while traveling.  Destroy him.  Unlocks 'Demonblood' class.

  *Note: While [it is possible](https://steamcommunity.com/app/588950/discussions/0/1693785035811504858/) to beat Sky Eater normally, it's extremely difficult.  You'll have a much easier time if you first go through the **Dark Lord** ending path, but choose 'Return to Overworld'.  This gives you enormously overpowered stats.*